# Custom tableview cell is not appearing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created a core data model for a sign up page which worked properly but when I attach a table view to that sign up page my custom table cell data is not appearing.

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class FifthViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var Table1: UITableView!

    var array = ["central","gvk","forum"]

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return array.count
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = Table1.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        cell.label1.text = self.array[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

TableViewCell

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
}
```

Comment: have you confirmed data source and delegate ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this it will help you:

```
class FifthViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var Table1: UITableView!

var array = ["central","gvk","forum"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Table1.delegate = self
    Table1.dataSource = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return array.count
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    cell.label1.text = self.array[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
}
```

You forgot to call:
`Table1.datasource = self` and `Table1.delegate = self`

Without calling datasource tableview will not show any data.

Comment: I have connected datasource and delegates even though it isn't showing up

Answer (score 1):

I have connected both datasource and delegate even though it isn't showing up the data when i used simple tableview without customizing it is working properly, so I thought of using reload data.

Comment: Check my updated answer, you will also need to register cell in view did load

Comment: @IBAction func logOut(_ sender: Any) {
        
        let userDetailsVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FifthViewController") as! FifthViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(userDetailsVC, animated: true)
        
    }

Comment: I have given that action to a button to get tableview but im unable to get data of custom cell why

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
class FifthViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var Table1: UITableView!

 override func viewDidLoad(){
    //In View did load  
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Register the table view cell class and its reuse id
    self.tableView.register(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:"cell")


    Table1.delegate = self //If not set in story board or Xib
    Table1.datasource = self //If not set in story board or Xib
    var array = ["central","gvk","forum"]
    Table1.reloadData()
    }


     func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
    }
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return array.count
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? TableViewCell
        if cell==nil
        {
            //initialize the cell here
            cell = TableViewCell.init(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        }        

        cell.label1.text = self.array[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
 }
```

And before all of this check for identifier in the design of Custom table view cell in story board or xib It should be same as above in cell for row index path
Note : This is just pseudo code, might contain error

And also you can check full tutorial, [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-from-scratch-with-swift-table-view-basics--cms-25160)

Comment: why need Table1.reloadData()? .

Comment: If that code should go in `viewDidLoad`, why not show that? And you should set the table's `dataSource` too if it and the `delegate` are not already set in the storyboard.

Comment: @rmaddy yes if they are not set in story board we need to set both, I have updated the answer

Comment: @TusharSharma we need to reload data because if view controller is not subclass of UITableViewController, the table view will not load by it self

Comment: @HiteshSultaniya That is not true, try without reloading it will still work fine.

Comment: @TusharSharma okay but still we will need to reload it after initializing data array

Comment: @HiteshSultaniya In op question array data is not coming from server, as you can see he has 3 index value fixed. So no need to reload. In case data coming from server or database which will work in background, in that case we reload after obtaining complete data.

Comment: **Never** register a cell unless you are using an extra nib or the table view is created in code.

Comment: how to initialize cell?

Comment: @DixithMaram I have added initlization in my answer, please check for syntax error as I am not sure about syntax for now

Comment: The optional binding in the *dequeue* line is also a bad suggestion. Force-unwrapping as in the question is correct. The code must not crash if everything is hooked up properly.

Comment: I have used a button in previous page of tableview to get data from custom cell is there any seperate protocol to get data of custom cell using button?

Comment: You can use didSelect delegate method of UTableView to get data of custom cell, This method is called when you tap or select any cell

Comment: @DixithMaram if your problem is solved regarding asked question please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe old but for those who have same problem now.

For Table view chose `Content -> Static cells`